# GoogleMock: Expect either of two method calls

Tags: c++, testing, mocking, googlemock

I have a class `Foo` that references multiple other objects of type `IBar`. The class has a method `fun` that needs to invoke method `frob` on at least one of those `IBar`s. I want to write a test with mocked `IBar`s that verifies this requirement. I'm using GoogleMock. I currently have this:

```
class IBar { public: virtual void frob() = 0; };
class MockBar : public IBar { public: MOCK_METHOD0(frob, void ()); };

class Foo {
  std::shared_ptr<IBar> bar1, bar2;
public:
  Foo(std::shared_ptr<IBar> bar1, std::shared_ptr<IBar> bar2)
      : bar1(std::move(bar1)), bar2(std::move(bar2))
  {}
  void fun() {
    assert(condition1 || condition2);
    if (condition1) bar1->frob();
    if (condition2) bar2->frob();
  }
}

TEST(FooTest, callsAtLeastOneFrob) {
  auto bar1 = std::make_shared<MockBar>();
  auto bar2 = std::make_shared<MockBar>();
  Foo foo(bar1, bar2);

  EXPECT_CALL(*bar1, frob()).Times(AtMost(1));
  EXPECT_CALL(*bar2, frob()).Times(AtMost(1));

  foo.fun();
}
```

However, this doesn't verify that either `bar1->frob()` or `bar2->frob()` is called, only that neither is called more than once.

Is there a way in GoogleMock to test for a minimum number of calls on a group of expectations, like a `Times()` function I can call on an `ExpectationSet`?

Comment: Consider just splitting this up into two tests: one for each condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved using [check points](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#using-check-points-usingcheckpoints):

```
using ::testing::MockFunction;

MockFunction<void()> check_point;
EXPECT_CALL(*bar1, frob())
    .Times(AtMost(1))
    .WillRepeatedly(
        InvokeWithoutArgs(&check_point, &MockFunction<void()>::Call);
EXPECT_CALL(*bar2, frob())
    .Times(AtMost(1))
    .WillRepeatedly(
        InvokeWithoutArgs(&check_point, &MockFunction<void()>::Call);
EXPECT_CALL(check_point, Call())
    .Times(Exactly(1));
```

Comment: Add missing closing parenthesis in `WillRepeatedly` of first two `EXPECT_CALL`